# How to write query/trigger that satisfies following scenario?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Solution required in SQL Server.

Suppose there are 2 tables

1. `TICKET` table with following columns:

   - item_id - PK
   - ticket_cost
2. `TICKET_PAST` with columns:

   - price - FK
   - ticket_new_cost

The question is to write a trigger such that whenever a price in the `TICKET` table is inserted, updated or deleted a new row should be generated by trigger?

Comment: You are going to need the `item_id` as the foreign key in the `item_hist` table.

Answer (score 2):

Using an `after update` trigger, and accessing the new value from `inserted` and the old value from `deleted`:

```
create trigger dbo.item_price_update_trigger 
  on dbo.item 
    after update as
begin;
  set nocount on;
  insert into item_hist (item_id, price, new_price)
  select i.item_id, d.price, i.price
  from inserted i 
    inner join deleted d
      on i.item_id = d.item_id
end;
go
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PBB85814

---

This trigger answers your question, but would most likely be just one of three triggers for a complete auditing/history solution. You may want a trigger for `after insert` to store the initial insert of an item, and an `after delete` trigger to record the final price of an item that was deleted.

You would also probably want to include the dates of when these actions occurred, so you could query what the effective price was of an item at a given time.

For a somewhat automated option of creating audit/history tables and related triggers, this article and the related scripts may be helpful: [Quick And Easy Audit Tables - Dave Britten](http://dave.brittens.org/blog/quick-and-easy-audit-tables.html)

---

Reference:

- [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables)
- [`create trigger` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)
- [DML Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers)